# Jenkins agent as variable at the stage level in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple Jenkins worker nodes, and a declarative jenkins pipeline. 
I would like to create a choice parameter at each stage in order to allow worker node selection. Is this possible ?

At the pipeline top level I have :

```
pipeline {
        agent { label 'node1||node2' }

...
```

I know that it the agent can be also specified at the stage level:

```
stage("Test") {

          agent {label "node1"}
...
}
```

But I would like something like this:

```
stage('Test') {
            agent { label  
                parameters {
                 choice choices: ['node1', 'node2'], description:  name: 'jenkins_worker' 
                           } 
             }
}
```

Is this possible from the syntax point of view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare agent as parameter:

```
pipeline {
        agent { label parameters.AGENT }
...
```

Overwrite it in stage:

```
stage('Test') {
     AGENT="node1"
  }
```